# Como fazer upload de aquivos para o servidor?

Tags: php, html

Tenho o seguinte código html e php a rodar no meu servidor, no entanto, sempre que tento fazer o upload de um arquivo, é-me retornada a mensagem "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!" e não consigo perceber porquê...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

<?PHP
  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }
?>
```

O meu servidor é Apache/2.4.25 (Debian).

Será que me conseguem ajudar?

Comment: Aparentemente o seu problema é na definição da variável $path. Esse diretório uploads está no mesmo nível do arquivo upload.php? Coloca provisoriamente \error_reporting(\E_ALL); no início do arquivo upload.php para ter noção exata do erro gerado por move_uploaded_file.

Comment: [Aqui tem um exemplo](https://github.com/davidchc/tutorial-upload-de-arquivo-com-ajax) pronto.

Comment: @Benilson sim o diretório uploads está no mesmo nível do arquivo upload.php. Coloquei o error_reporting(\E_ALL); e foi-me retornado o número 22527...

Comment: @IvanFerrer tentei com esse exemplo e foi-me retornada a mensagem "Erro ao enviar"...

Comment: O seu erro, é quando ele tenta chamar move_uploaded_file, por algum motivo ele não está com permissão de mover da pasta temporária para o diretório de upload, talvez o problema esteja na pasta upload que deve estar sem permissão de escrita, experimente escrever a pasta: `chmod(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/upload/"), 0755) `, ou algo assim...

Comment: Troca `$path = "uploads/";` por `$path = __DIR__ . "/uploads/";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***FAÇA UM TESTE***, uso este código. (obviamente muda para a sua estrutura)

```
 <?php  

        $foto = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];

   //FOTO
    $tamanho_permitido = "1024000"; //1 MB
    $pasta = 'uploads';

    if (!empty($foto)){
    $file = getimagesize($foto);

    //TESTA O TAMANHO DO ARQUIVO
    if($_FILES['image']['size'] > $tamanho_permitido){
        echo "Erro - Arquivo muito grande";
        exit();
    }

    //TESTA A EXTENSÃO DO ARQUIVO
    if(!preg_match('/^image\/(?:gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i', $file['mime'])){
        echo "Erro - extensão não permitida";
        exit();
    }

    //CAPTURA A EXTENSÃO DO ARQUIVO
    $extensao = str_ireplace("/", "", strchr($file['mime'], "/"));

    //MONTA O CAMINHO DO NOVO DESTINO
    $novoDestino = "{$pasta}/imagem_".uniqid('', true) . '.' . $extensao;  
    move_uploaded_file ($foto , $novoDestino );

} 

        include('conexaobd.php');

        $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO pacientes (uploaded_file) VALUES ('$novoDestino')";

        mysqli_query($link, $sqlinsert) or die("Não foi possível armazenar no banco");

        $resultado = "Dados Cadastrados com Sucesso!!";

        ?>
```

**Salva o caminho da imagem no banco de dados, e a imagem em si no diretório.**